# What is .jspa URL extension in web applications?

Tags: jsp, web-applications, java-ee-6

In many online web applications, I notice that the application url ends with jspa. My assumption is it is a jsp and action is mapped to jspa instead of *.do.

Is my understanding correct or there is an actual extension/different meaning? Kindly suggest and  ignore if this question is very basic. I googled already and could not get clear answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> In many online web applications, I notice that the application url
> ends with jspa. My assumption is it is a jsp and action is mapped to
> jspa instead of *.do.

Your assumption is *almost* correct. Why I have used the word, *almost* is because you have mentioned that it is a JSP. In fact, it can be anything; not just a JSP. The URL contains a logical name and it may be mapped to a Servlet, JSP or any other thing. The URL, http://www.sun.com/training/catalog/courses/CX-310-083.xml looks like an XML document at first sight but it is actually not. The actual content is rendered based on the [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header i.e. you can see a URL with extension `.abc` which may actually render an `HTML` page.

Comment: This answer is technically correct but doesn't answer the OP's real question.  Of course the extension _could_ be anything, but extensions _tend_ to tell us something about the underlying application - **this is the question.**

Answer (score 3):

Most probably just like JavaServer Pages (JSP) is a Java standard technology that enables you to write dynamic, data-driven pages for your Java web applications.